# How to remove last path of NSURL with special characters

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

So I'm a little confused. I have an NSURL like this

```
https://something/something/test#4.html
```

I want to remove the last path of this. I tried using URLByDeletingLastPathComponent method but then it results in this.

```
https://something/something/#4.html
```

I want the end result to be the following.

```
https://something/something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smart way to remove the fragment is `URLComponents`

```
let url = URL(string: "https://something/something/test#4.html")!

if var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) {
    urlComponents.fragment = nil
    let trimmedURL = urlComponents.url!.deletingLastPathComponent()
    print(trimmedURL)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove the fragment. Then the last path using `deletingLastPathComponent()`.

```
var url = URL(string: "https://something/something/test#4.html")

if let fragment = url?.fragment{
    url = URL(string: (url?.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "#\(fragment)", with: ""))!)
    url = url?.deletingLastPathComponent()
}

print(url!)
```

Comment: Don't use NSURL. Use URL.